# Angular ng-blur is being triggered on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a textarea that when one types the hash symbol "#" the focus switches to an input. The issue I am having is that when the cursor switches to the input element it is triggering the ng-blur function.

`angular.element('#inputElement').focus();` is triggering a blur event.

Why is it triggering ng-blur? That makes no sense to me.

**See the demo:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/D3dOj90I3uQlz0OGaNjV?p=preview

Comment: Looks like a bug, at least ya, not expected behaviour. Using a timeout fixes it: `setTimeout(function(){angular.element('#inputElement').focus();},0);`  http://plnkr.co/edit/b6iDvLrM1eI4jAM1Gr6x?p=preview

Comment: @A.Wolff Brilliant fix, how did you think of using a Timeout?

Comment: For what it's worth I can only reproduce this in Chrome. Both IE and Firefox seem to work as expected.

Comment: Seems related to `keypress event` on chrome, cannot be reproduced using `keyup event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. The best thing you can do is set up an event that will do nothing, perhaps `e.preventDefault()` during blur.

Have you tried using a directive and instead of grabbing the element through `angular.element("#inputElement")` you use the built-in `element`?

Comment: preventDefault() fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the answer for this other question: [ng-focus firing twice and ng-blur never fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804949/ng-focus-firing-twice-and-ng-blur-never-fires/32514380#32514380)

In short... try turning all extensions off in Chrome, and see if that makes the problem go away. The original question writer for the link above had problems because of the Angular Batarang. I personally am having problems with AdBlock... both extensions seem to be interfering with the DOM events in some manner.